# rake assets:precompile trying to connect to production database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, precompile

```
$ rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Network is unreachable
    Is the server running on host "192.168.163.70" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby /...]
```

So I'm trying to precompile assets on my development box. For some reason it tries to connect to the production database (192.168.163.70) and when it fails to do so, it aborts.

Why does it do that and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following line in one of my Rake task files

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../..', 'config', 'environment'))
```

Removing it solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, even if there are no rake tasks in my project. rake insists on connecting to the production database when precompiling assets. I can temporarily solve it by changing database.yml to point  production to the dev database, but that makes it easy to deploy pointing to the wrong database. Any better solutions?

Comment: I'd try to debug and find what causes the asset precompilation to load the production configs. Unfortunately, I don't have better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

check your RAILS_ENV, it must be set to `production` at the moment.

Comment: puts Rails.env gives "development" before Application.load_tasks

Comment: what about `echo $RAILS_ENV`? Also, check your `database.yml`, maybe you something wrong there.